# Event scheduled reminders not sending with fixed date

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

I've been doing a bunch of testing on this on my site running Civicrm 5.13.5 and Drupal 7 after my event scheduled reminders were not working.

From what i can work out, if the original reminder has a fixed date (eg, 19th Sept 2019) the first email goes out but no subsequent repeats go out. No errors in the cron log.

But if the original reminder has a date like "1 hour after event start date", the repeats work.

The steps I used to reproduce were:

1. Make sure cron is working and schedule reminders set to hourly
2. create a test event
3. make a scheduled reminder with fixed date and repeat every hour till a year after event start.
4. only the first reminder is delivered
5. set a reminder with relative date (1 hour after start date) repeat every hour until a year after start date.
6. works as expected.

Is this a known bug? Fixed in a later version maybe. I'm happy to do more testing, file an issue in gitlab. Whatever is most useful.

Just wanted to post here in case it helps anyone else.

Can be a pretty annoying bug when you have a reminder set to trigger each week like we did. And you have to wait a week to check if it worked or not.

Comment: I'm testing this on a similar setup to see if I can replicate the problem, we'll know in an hour or two

Comment: yep. seems like a bug. I was able to replicate the problem
civicrm  5.17.4; Drupal 7.67

 if you have not already, post it as an issue on gitlab. and if you could post the link to the gitlab issue here I'd appreciate it

Comment: Issue posted here:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1271